# I'm trying to automate the worldcheck website. I'm unable to fill the search box through selenium IDE. For Scripting i'm using Python

Tags: python, selenium-ide

```
<div class="input-con">
   <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="mohammed ali thani">
</div>
```

This is the code of lines used in Selenium for filling the input field.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("name").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("name").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys("mohammed ali thani")
```

It shows the error: Unable to locate the element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#name"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using find_element_by_xpath()

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="name"]').send_keys("mohammed ali thani")
```

Also, I would suggest using `driver.wait()` after the `driver.find_element_by_id("name").click()`

Comment: Thanks. I had to switch the frames before this particular id and it accepted the input then.